# How to input this vector (1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9) simply using seq()&rep()?

Tags: r

The vector `(1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9)` 
`seq()` and `rep()` maybe can not deliver parameters.
I read the help doc but fail to find the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try

```
 (1:5) + rep(0:4,each=5)
 #[1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

**NOTE:** `(1:5)` and `0:4` can be replaced by `seq(1,5)` and `seq(0,4)`

Answer (score 3):

Another one:

```
as.vector(outer(1:5,0:4,"+"))
```